# How to set a name to the TITLE of a newly opened tab from the @Html.ActionLink cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

My current code in `Index.cshtml` page:

```
@Html.ActionLinks(@Html.ActionLink(objList.Name, "Name", "ControllerName", new {Id=objList.Id}, new {target = "_blank"}))
```

The above code makes me to open a page(`Name.cshtml`) in a new tab after clicking a link in the `Index` page. But my goal is to assign a name(`objList.Name`) as a `Title` for the new tab. 
 So, I added the Title attribute in the following code but it is not working as expected.

```
 @Html.ActionLinks(@Html.ActionLink(objList.Name, "Name", "ControllerName", new {Id=objList.Id}, new {target = "_blank", title = objList.Name}))
```

How to acheive this?

Comment: In you name.cshtml markup - <title>My Title</title>

Comment: Thers is no markup mentioned as <title>..</title> in `name.cshtml` page

Comment: Yes - add that markup to your cshtml page - you dont need any of that extra code in Action Link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the objList.Name as a parameter to the "Name" action, in this action you can include the name in the Viewbag:

```
ViewBag.MyTitle = nameParameter;
```

And in the "Name" view:

```
<title>@ViewBag.MyTitle</title>
```

If you are using a Layout page, you only have to put this in the "name" action:

```
ViewBag.Title = nameParameter;
```

Because in your layout view you probably have this:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Comment: Working fine as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 'title' in your code is adding a mouseover title on the link, I think.

To have the title in the tab, use the solution from carlos (put the title tag and viewbag prop in your viewpage).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `Name` into the `RouteValueDictionary`, add it to your `ActionResult` and then set `ViewBag.Title`.

First, change your `ActionLink` to be:

```
Html.ActionLinks(@Html.ActionLink(objList.Name, "Name", "ControllerName", new {Id=objList.Id, Name=objList.Name}, new {target = "_blank"}))
```

Then create a model (if you don't have one on the Name table), something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your `Name` `ActionResult` to be:

```
    public ActionResult Name(int Id, string Name)
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel 
        {
            Id = Id,
            Name = Name
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Then add the model to your `Name` view:

```
@model MyModel
```

Then set `ViewBag.Title` in the `Name` view:

```
ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
```