# Get Column title in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, parameters, title, actionlink

MVC5 did a great job on automatically creating the View page (Razor). It currently displays my list of Students for example with table heading like this:

```
<th>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })*@
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
</th>
```

Now. ***DisplayNameFor*** take a Lambda Expression as its parameter. 
However, **I want the Column title**, which is "Last Name", to pass into another HtmlHelper's parameter - ***ActionLink***'s.
Following articles seem to be similar but I read it, unfortunately it didn't solve my problem:

- [How to set a name to the TITLE of a newly opened tab from the @Html.ActionLink cshtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076608/how-to-set-a-name-to-the-title-of-a-newly-opened-tab-from-the-html-actionlink-c?rq=1)
- [How to get the column titles from the Display(Name=) DataAnnotation for a strongly typed list scaffold view at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947854/how-to-get-the-column-titles-from-the-displayname-dataannotation-for-a-strong?rq=1)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit? `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)` should display "LastName". What other HtmlHelper are you trying to use? You may just need to use the string "Last Name".

Comment: Also please tell us how the "column title" is specified. Columns don't have titles, in general.

Comment: in general for just passing the value use model.LastName, the Lambda is used to point at the property the value comes from to find other metadata for display and validation

Comment: I think by "column title" he means "field name."

Comment: Maybe you could give a little background about why you are trying to achieve this. For instance, why is it not good enough to just put the field name in the action link: `@Html.ActionLink("Field Name", "Linked View")`.

Comment: @abalter: ActionLink is the other HtmlHelper that I'm trying to use. Passing in "Last Name" as string works fine, but that's hard-coded.

Comment: to YishaiGalatzer: model.LastName (through loops) returns the value of an instance, great; the Lambda returns the property, supper.
But I'm working with the table heading (expecting them to be links), and now I want the string "Last Name" to pass in as a parameter of @Html.ActionLink. I can give ActionLink a string "Last Name" as a parameter, but I don't want to hard-code it. Something like Model.LastName.DisplayNameThatIsGivenAsAttributeInClassDesign() would be really helpful in my case.

Comment: Right, you want something like `@Html.ActionLink(@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FieldName), "Page"))`. But I tried it, and I don't think you can nest helpers. Would you accept a hybrid Ajax solution? If so, I think I can figure one out.

Comment: Could you provide just a bit more information about how you want to use it . Like, do you want to be able to use a for loop to create a set of links for each column name?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` does not accept an expression as a parameter. You will need to write your own html helper extension method.

Comment: Thank you abalter, but I think using resources (from Alex Art) is the way to go. That would help me later on the I18N issue as well.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: `DisplayNameFor` HtmlHelper extension from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947854/how-to-get-the-column-titles-from-the-displayname-dataannotation-for-a-strong?rq=1) wouldn't help. I need a string to pass onto `Html.ActionLink()`, not MvcHtmlString.

Comment: No I mean you need to create your own html helper method that accepts an expression!

Comment: Well, that clarifies it. But ... `ContosoUniversity` ... I'm still learning the basics. Anyhow, thank you all! Using resources seems to be the solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Resources for this:

1. Add Resource LastNameTitle
2. Your model will look like:

   ```
   public class Model
   {

       [Display(Name = "LastNameTitle ", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
       public string LastName{ get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Your View:

   ```
   <th>
       @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Resources.LastNameTitle , "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
   </th>
   ```

Comment: It's just what I need. Thanks so much!  
Although I'm sure there's a way for me to manage all of these resources (like in a folder) or something right? Because later on I would want properties on other classes to have ResourceType like this one. How do I make it centralized in like one folder only?

Comment: I'm trying out your solution. And.... How do I add Resource LastNameTitle again?  :smiley face:

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati
You can get an Idea on how to use resources

Comment: This is a useful link as well. It contains a lot of code for I18N but it also explains how to work with resources

Comment: These might also be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displaycolumnattribute(v=vs.95).aspx      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Wonderful! I'm a little lazy here. Help me out will you?
When (in Student Index View)
`@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>`  became  `@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>`   , this    `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName) ` causes an error. :(

Comment: Anyway, thank you. The problem has been resolved by using resources.

Comment: Regarding your issue, you cant use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)` since you model now is  not a student but a `IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>`. and clearly `IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>` doesn't have FirstName property

Comment: It's actually from a IEnumerable list of student to a paged list of student. :D

Comment: Well, it actually doesn't matter since `PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>` doesn't have FirstName property either.